# Positioning with `current axis` depending on limits?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, calculations

I try to specify the `x axis label` position below the x axis arrow at the same baseline like the `xticklabels`. It works fine for most plots. However, when modifying the range of the y axis with `ymin=...`, the coordinate of `current axis.south east` changes (which I don't like), but in addition, the position of the coordinate changes towards an unexpected direction.

What is the reason that truncated plots result in a strangely modified `current axis` environment?

In the following, pictures with `ymin=1.0` (ok), `ymin=0.8` (ok), `ymin=1.2` (undesirable result), and `ymin` not defined (strange result) are provided, together with an MWE.

[image: ymin=1.0, result ok]
[image: ymin=0.8, result ok]
[image: ymin=1.2, result undesirable]
[image: no ymin, result strange]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        every axis x label/.style={at={($ (current axis.south east) + (0,-2.135pt)$)},red,anchor=base,yshift=-0.75em},
        xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-0.75em},
        xlabel={$t$}, 
        ymin=1.0, % <-- min of addplot
        %ymin=1.2, % <-- random truncation
    ]
    \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With alternate solutions provided below, I am still interested what causes a weird positioning using `current axis.south east`... Is this a bug in `pgfplots` or have I understood the meaning of `current axis` in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `xticklabel cs` to position the `x axis label`:

```
every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)},anchor=south,red},
typeset ticklabels with strut,
xlabel={$t$\strut},
```

The `\strut` inside `xlabel` and option `typeset ticklabels with strut` are used to ensure that the ticklabels and the label have the same height and the same depth.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ymin in {.8,1,1.2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1)},anchor=south,red},
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        xlabel={$t$\strut}, 
        ymin=\ymin
    ]
    \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**:

If you really want to manually shift the `x axis label` by absolute values like in your example use either

```
at={([yshift=-2.135pt]current axis.south east)}
```

or

```
at={($ (current axis.south east) + (0pt,-2.135pt)$)}
```

Note, that you have to use `0pt` instead only `0`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \ymin in {.8,1,1.2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={($ (current axis.south east) + (0pt,-2.135pt)$)},
            red,anchor=base,yshift=-0.75em
        },
        xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-0.75em},
        xlabel={$tg$}, 
        ymin=\ymin
    ]
    \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. However, I would also like to understand what causes my MWE to crash. Is this a bug in pgfplots or have I understood the meaning of `current axis` in a wrong way?

Comment: @kromuchi See my updated answer. You have to use `0pt` instead only `0` for the x direction.

Comment: Crazy, that (wrong) units for `x` coordinates effect the `y` position.

Comment: For further reference: There is also a similar coordinate system to `xticklabel cs` that ignores the height of x labels: `xticklabel* cs`